# Possible to have more than one virtual document root for the same subdomain?

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I am setting up a development server and I would like to know if it is possible to set up more than one virtual host that serves as a fallback for the same subdomain using a virtual document root?

To clarify, say I have this virtual host, which basically allows for dynamic subdomains under `ex1.somedomain.com`, the folder name becomes the name of the subdomain. This all works just fine.

```
<VirtualHost [ip address here]:80>
   UseCanonicalName off
   VirtualDocumentRoot /home/firstuser/www/%1/public_html/
   ServerAlias *.ex1.somedomain.com

   <Directory /home/firstuser/www/*/public_html/>
      AllowOverride all
   </Directory>

   AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
   Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
   Alias /php5-fcgi /home/firstuser/www/php5-fcgi
   FastCgiExternalServer /home/firstuser/www/php5-fcgi -socket /tmp/php5-fpm-firstuser.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 600
</VirtualHost>
```

That said.. for organizational and permissions related reasons, I thought I could add another virtualhost right after it that would serve as a fallback, if the folder didn't exist in the first virtual document root. For example, if `/home/firstuser/www/test` did not exist, it would try the next virtualhost and see if `/home/seconduser/www/test` existed and serve up that content if it did.. but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<VirtualHost [ip address here]:80>
   UseCanonicalName off
   VirtualDocumentRoot /home/seconduser/www/%1/public_html/
   ServerAlias *.ex1.somedomain.com

   <Directory /home/seconduser/www/*/public_html/>
      AllowOverride all
   </Directory>

   AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
   Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
   Alias /php5-fcgi /home/seconduser/www/php5-fcgi
   FastCgiExternalServer /home/seconduser/www/php5-fcgi -socket /tmp/php5-fpm-seconduser.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 600
</VirtualHost>
```

What is the correct way to configure something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in support to hop from one virtualhost to another if a file doesn't exist, but there are recipes in the mod_rewrite manual that show you how to poke around in  the filesystem before changing the URI to filesystem mapping.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#multipledirs

```
RewriteEngine on

#   first try to find it in dir1/...
#   ...and if found stop and be happy:
RewriteCond         "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dir1/%{REQUEST_URI}"  -f
RewriteRule "^(.+)" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dir1/$1"  [L]

#   second try to find it in dir2/...
#   ...and if found stop and be happy:
RewriteCond         "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dir2/%{REQUEST_URI}"  -f
RewriteRule "^(.+)" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dir2/$1"  [L]

#   else go on for other Alias or ScriptAlias directives,
#   etc.
RewriteRule   "^"  "-"  [PT]
```